# Restrict POST request to be called only from my Android application

Tags: android, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am creating an app with appengine to manage datastore queries from my Android application.
I want certain parts of the appengine app to be executed only if the request comes from my Android application.

For example, if I want to create a new user, I create a POST request from my Android application and this POST is executed in my appengine app, creating a new entity in the datastore. I don't want people to create a form in a webpage and call the same POST request to create users outside the Android app.

What's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give your app a key that has to be passed to the server to post.

Another approach would be to send a challenge from your server to your client at the beginning of protocole communication and then see if the client can find the solution. A typical challenge like this uses asymetric keys.

Comment: I thought about the key, but how? Just a string I make up my self? Wouldn't be this unsafe? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just a string. And no, that wouldn't be very safe as the key would be inside the app. If you use asymetrical keys, that would still be the same, a bit more complicated but the problem is that there is no way that the client app can both identify itself and shouldn't contain the information to identify itself and be protected against decompiling. That information will always be present on the client side.